# How to setup Toggle Key to display the shell script output during execution?

Tags: bash, shell

In my team they have asked me to create a shell script with toggle key option to display the command output/errors when a arrow key is pressed. And it need to hide the output when the same arrow key is pressed. Is there a way we can achieve this using a shell script?

I don't have a solution yet but the script which we are using now is throwing so many output and its making the screen loaded without so many lines of std output/errors during execution. And we would like to hide the output using the toggle key and when needed if we press a key it needs to display the output during execution.

No idea on how to start with this. Need some idea or thoughts on how to achieve this?

**Expected:**
Shrink the output using toggle key (say for example UP arrow key) and when needed if we press the same UP arrow key it need to display the output again.

**Actual:**
No code available as of now to do this function.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just log it to syslog and just filter it post?

Comment: They want to me to do this on the fly when the script is executing.

Comment: So? I am not talking about user interaction. You can store to syslog, then when you want to switch, you kill current `tail -f`, and `clear` the screen and do another `tail -f` from the syslog with different filtering options.

Comment: Which OS/distribution/version do you use?

Comment: In SLES 15 I need to do this. They are migrating the cluster resources from SLES 11 to SLES 15 and they want me to create a script for that purpose.